# Convert JSON into CSV (again)

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm having a nightmare trying to get my JSON into a CSV, I've tried to follow the other threads on here but I'm an absolute novice at this and have struggled a great deal, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very greatful.

I'll include JSON sample below, sorry for repeating a question that has been asked many times.

```
{
"ApiMessage": "Inventory Returned",
"ApiNumber": "InvS001",
"inventoryResponse": [
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT3",
        "Total_Stock": 0,
        "Unavailable": 0
    },
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT4",
        "Total_Stock": 2,
        "Unavailable": 1
    },
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT5",
        "Total_Stock": 0,
        "Unavailable": 0
    },
```

I just want it so I can have a CSV file with three columns and the values in each

So..

```
Sku ID         Total_Stock          Unavailable
dsdsdsdsd           2                    0
```

Comment: You can  use `csv.DictWriter` for this task @Sean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write the list of dictionaries to a file

```
import csv

dct = {
"ApiMessage": "Inventory Returned",
"ApiNumber": "InvS001",
"inventoryResponse": [
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT3",
        "Total_Stock": 0,
        "Unavailable": 0
    },
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT4",
        "Total_Stock": 2,
        "Unavailable": 1
    },
    {
        "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT5",
        "Total_Stock": 0,
        "Unavailable": 0
    }] }

#Open csv file
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    #Open dict writer with fieldnames
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=['Sku_Id', 'Total_Stock', 'Unavailable'], delimiter=',')
    #Write header and write all rows
    writer.writeheader()
    print(writer.writerows(dct['inventoryResponse']))
```

The output will be

```
Sku_Id,Total_Stock,Unavailable
007BLKWHT3,0,0
007BLKWHT4,2,1
007BLKWHT5,0,0
```

Comment: Thankyou for the swift reply, I am grateful for you reaching out. But this code seems to put all values into one column rather than three seperate columns? Unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: There are three separate columns if you see the expected output file I posted @Sean Isn't that what you are seeing in your output?

Comment: For some reason when I open in Excel as a CSV they seem to be in column A?

Comment: That is because I used a tab delimiter, since you said the csv should look like Sku ID Total_Stock Unavailable, change the delimiter to delimiter=',' and we should be good!  @Sean Check my updated answer too!

Comment: Thank you so much Devesh, that has worked a dream! Exactly what I was trying to achieve, I'm greatful for your help! If I can pick your brain once more, there seems to be a blank line between each row, is there a tweak for the code I can do to get rid of the blank rows? Thankyou once again

Comment: Great! Glad to help @Sean ! If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick next to it :) Please also consider taking a look at stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :) Also it depends where you are opening the file in, If I open the file in a normal text editor, it looks the way I posted in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to read in the json and then export to CSV.

Here is an example of doing this in one line:

https://copdips.com/2018/06/converting-python-json-list-to-csv-in-2-lines-of-code-by-pandas.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution on hand so it's not best (You can use `csv`, `pandas` or one of many libs for that, it can be done to look better, but if you just need it to do this one thing one time I believe it will do the job:

```py
myjson = {
    "ApiMessage": "Inventory Returned",
    "ApiNumber": "InvS001",
    "inventoryResponse": [
        {
            "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT3",
            "Total_Stock": 0,
            "Unavailable": 0
        },
        {
            "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT4",
            "Total_Stock": 2,
            "Unavailable": 1
        },
        {
            "Sku_Id": "007BLKWHT5",
            "Total_Stock": 0,
            "Unavailable": 0
        }
    ]
}

DELIMITER = "         "

with open("my_file.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(DELIMITER.join(["Sku ID", "Total_Stock", "Unavailable"]) + "\n")
    for item in myjson["inventoryResponse"]:
        csvfile.write(DELIMITER.join([str(e) for e in item.values()]) + "\n")
```